# Create MVC application with CRUD functions

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, jdbc, crud

I'm currently new to Java EE and not yet experienced on Java SE & EE.

We were given a project were we will create a web app with create, update and delete functions with JDBC. The main requirement is to use MVC.  We thought MVC pattern and Struts 1 framework.  I'm thinking of using other framework instead of Struts 1.

What do you think is a good framework that would be suited to a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Grails](http://grails.org)

The first time I start MVC web app with struts 1.3 because a lot of tutorial and document available.

Answer (score 0):

For learning purpose, I highly recommend you to use Spring ROO to create CRUD web project. Just follow the document on the Spring ROO page. You can have a web project up and running on a server in 10 minutes. And you can select to use some of the popular frameworks, database, etc..
Then you can study the auto created project like structure, patterns, good practices and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of using Struts 1 switch to Struts 2. There are so many alternatives available for MVC in Java alone. I would mainly consider Spring MVC and JSF to be alternatives for Struts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Java EE and not experienced in Java I would suggest to start with Spring MVC and some basic step-by-step examples.

You may try to make use first of spring's jdbcTemplate classes to query databases and switch to JPA if you are ready. You will need to learn some spring annotations like @Controller, @RequestMapping, @ModelAttribute and so on, but once done, you will be happy.

You may also need some background with JSP and servlets as well, basic examples will help you with it for sure and will help you understand the Spring MVC concepts.

I do not recommend Spring Roo for starter, as it may overwhelm you when you start to change it to your requirements. Other reasonable alternatives for you are: Struts2.

I also encourage to use maven for building you app and Tomcat or Jetty as application server.